# Moment locale to get day of week

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to use Moment.day() to get the day of the week. How to confirm if it is using Monday as 1 and Sunday as 7 . I am not sure whether to use **moment.locale('en')** or **moment.isoWeek**. Any guidance on which one to use.

Thank you

Comment: Good trick: Go to momentjs.com, open a console, `moment().day()` and you can see what it returns.  The method you need for your app is up to you.  Also, if you're starting a new app with Moment, don't.  It's no longer maintained because there are leaner alternatives out there. ;)

Comment: you could forget all that and just use JavaScript's Date API: `new Date().toLocaleDateString(undefined,{weekday:'long'});`

Comment: Check the docs! https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/

Comment: Thanks for the tips.